# joomla 2.5 custom extension about users

Tags: joomla2.5

I want your help to solve a problem in a site.

I know that when a user makes a subscription in the site through joomla log in form , it is stored in a table in sites database.
I want to the user to be stored in a custom table that I will make and it will be somewhere in the site.
The result I would like to be like this:

The site is for a school. Each student will made a subscription and his/her name will be stored to a table with lessons of the school. The teachers will log in the site and they will have to put the test results of each student in each lesson in this table.

it will be like:

> lesson 1----lesson 2-----lesson 3
>   user's name 1-------- grade----grade----------grade
>   user's name 2-------- grade----grade---------- grade

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have edited your post to remove teh frivolities and to fix a few English issues.  I have also marked your data using > and two trailing spaces on each line.

Please post your code and metadata you have so far.  What is your specific question ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look into custom [component creation](https://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Introduction).  As it is quite a simple component, the available component creators may do most of this for you. However it makes sense to understand the basics of how a component works first so that you know how to tweak and test it.

Simple components like this are ultimately just data entry into a single table, which is what most tutorials will cover.  Components get more complex when interacting with other components or require more tables.

If students do not need to log-in to the site (and if they are unlikely to in future), then they do not need to be made users, but rather can just be a component item which is created by the teachers when they enter the data.  If students need to log-in, then the id of the #__users table should be the match field in the new table.

When adding users to a site, it is important to make sure their permissions are set correctly so that they cannot access inappropriate data or make changes that they are not permitted to.

Also : If you are storing private information, it is particularly important that you keep Joomla patched for security - 2.5 is now rather out-of-date.